# Count of Events within a MongoDB Collection by Day within a Date Range

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

I am trying to figure out how to perform a count of events within a MongoDB collection, by all dates occurring within a specified date range.

Sample Document Schema within MongoDB:

```js
{
    eventNum: 1234,
    startDate:ISODate("2014-01-01"),
    endDate: ISODate("2014-01-04")
    eventType: System Crash
}
{
    eventNum: 4567,
    startDate: ISODate("2014-01-04"),
    endDate: ISODate("2014-01-05")
    eventType: Maintenance
}
```

What I am trying to get at is for the Date Range:

```js
1/1/2014 - 1/6/2014
```

What is the total count events for each day within this range?

Results would be:

```js
1/1/2014: 1
1/2/2014: 1
1/3/2014: 1
1/4/2014: 2
1/5/2014: 1
1/6/2014: 0
```

My problem really lies in the fact that the data being tracked is not on an individual day basis, which would have allowed me to perform a basic aggregation by Date.  The events have a start and end date.

Comment: Those "dates" look like strings to me, so that isn't going to help you. You will need to fix your strings to be actual "date" types as in there current form they will not compare in a lexical fashion anyhow.

Comment: Ok, I was just trying to mock up the example.   How would you go about doing this type of aggregation assuming they were valid dates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More of a [mapReduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.mapReduce/) problem unfortunately as you would otherwise not be able to emit the dates required to make this work.

```js
db.events.mapReduce(
    function() {
        var oneDay = ( 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 ),
            start = this.startDate.valueOf()
            - ( this.startDate.valueOf() % oneDay ),
            end = ((this.endDate.valueOf()
            - ( this.endDate.valueOf() % oneDay )) + oneDay);

        for ( var day = start; day < end; day += oneDay ) {
           emit ( new Date( day ), 1 );
        }
    },
    function(key, values) {
        return Array.sum( values );
    },
    { 
         "query": { 
             "startDate": { "$gte": new Date("2014-01-01") },
             "endDate": { "$lt": new Date("2014-01-06") }
          },
         "out": { "inline": 1 }
    }
)
```

If you really want the zero values for events that do not exist within the date range you can alter a little:

```js
db.events.mapReduce(
    function() {
        var oneDay = ( 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 ),
            start = this.startDate.valueOf()
            - ( this.startDate.valueOf() % oneDay ),
            end = ((this.endDate.valueOf()
            - ( this.endDate.valueOf() % oneDay )) + oneDay);

        for ( var day = start; day < end; day += oneDay ) {
           emit ( new Date( day ), 1 );
        }

        for ( var day = end; day <= ending.valueOf(); day += oneDay ) {
           emit( new Date( day ), 0 );
        }

    },
    function(key, values) {
        return Array.sum( values );
    },
    { 
         "query": { 
             "startDate": { "$gte": new Date("2014-01-01") },
             "endDate": { "$lt": new Date("2014-01-06") }
          },
          "scope": { "ending": new Date("2014-01-06") },
          "out": { "inline": 1 }
    }
)
```

Which gives you the output you want:

```js
   "results" : [
            {
                    "_id" : ISODate("2014-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                    "value" : 1
            },
            {
                    "_id" : ISODate("2014-01-02T00:00:00Z"),
                    "value" : 1
            },
            {
                    "_id" : ISODate("2014-01-03T00:00:00Z"),
                    "value" : 1
            },
            {
                    "_id" : ISODate("2014-01-04T00:00:00Z"),
                    "value" : 2
            },
            {
                    "_id" : ISODate("2014-01-05T00:00:00Z"),
                    "value" : 1
            },
            {
                    "_id" : ISODate("2014-01-06T00:00:00Z"),
                    "value" : 0
            }
]
```

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping there was some way to do this with the aggregation framework :(

Comment: @FarscapePROJ Sadly no as per my initial statement in the answer. There is no method available that would allow you to emit the dates between your startDate and endDate values as individual documents. That would require some sort of implementation of a "for loop" type of operator as was shown in the mapReduce approach here. But that does not yet exist.

Comment: @NeilLunn, a lot has changed in mongo over the last few years. Do you know if this answer still holds up? Is this still the only way to do this?